# How can I get PyCharm to recognize a custom property decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, pycharm, python-decorators

Let's consider the following example class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if self._bar is None:
            self._bar = ...  # a long computation
        return self._bar
```

I created a `cachedproperty` decorator to implicitly take care of storing the computed result as a member of the class instance. Here is a simplified example of such decorator class:

```
class cachedproperty(property):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        @functools.wraps(fget)
        def cfget(obj):
            name = '_' + fget.__name__
            if not hasattr(obj, name):
                setattr(obj, name, fget(obj))
            return getattr(obj, name)
        super().__init__(cfget)
```

And now class `Foo` looks like this:

```
class Foo:
    @cachedproperty
    def bar(self):
        return ...  # a long computation
```

Even though it works, it is somewhat inconvenient that PyCharm now fails to treat `bar` as a property of `Foo`, and instead treats it as a method. This can be witnessed, for example, in the autocompletion dropdown:

[image: Autocompletion for Foo.bar with @property decorator]

[image: Autocompletion for Foo.bar with @cachedproperty decorator]

My question is: how can I force PyCharm to treat my custom property decorator as an actual property?

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that PyCharm makes this decision purely based on the name of the decorator. For example, renaming your `cachedproperty` decorator to `cached_property` (so that it matches [Django's decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) of that name) works:

[image: Pycharm dropdown with property marker]

… whereas using the builtin `property` decorator with a different name doesn't:

[image: Pycharm dropdown with property marker]

Comment: That is very unfortunate, as I have several custom "property" decorators in my code, and I was hoping to be able to "tag" them accordingly for PyCharm